# Hyperbolic Geometry: Defect of a triangle

Tags: triangles, hyperbolic-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

I'm working on a problem and I needed an angle I couldn't find, so I looked it up in the solution manual off chegg-com.  And I do not understand what they are saying, can you help?
I copied the entire solution into this [pdf file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7of1mwmftwr03zm/6.2.8.pdf?dl=0).

I was following along just fine until the end of step 5.. what do they mean by "this is one of the defects"?  As I understand it the defect of a triangle is a single number and there can't be two.  (180 minus all three angles)  Then at the end of step 7, they say here's another defect.

Can anyone explain this to me?

I'd ask my professor, but she's gone out of town (again) and won't be back until after this is due.

Comment: Well, step 5, first equation, is a falsity, since they make the sum of the angles of a hyperbolic triangle add up to $180^\circ$. And so I, being somewhat informed in hyperbolic geometry, halt my reading right there. I think that the author of this answer is not correctly informed about the meaning of the hyperbolic defect of a triangle. Your understanding of the concept, as you sketch it in your question, seems to be right on the mark.

Comment: got any tips on solving the problem then?  I couldn't find angle CED which prevented me from finding the defect of that triangle.  I was going to subtract the defects of all the small triangles from ABC until only DEF was left.  But I can't get the defect of CED.

Comment: Here is my "finished" proof as I can't continue beyond this point.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/aezlyvz7hsry2li/6.2.8mine.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Sorry cannot open your file also here at stackexchange we would like you to put the whole question in the question (you can at graphics) also use Latex si

Comment: Can you provide some context? Are you sure they are talking about hyperbolic geometry? It sounds to me as if they might be talking about Euclidean geometry, and use “defect” not so much in terms of “angle defect” but more in terms of “inconsistency” of the described configuration. There can of course be multiple such inconsistencies.